# How to avoid PopReceiptMismatch errors in Azure durable functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

For my Azure functions application, a fan-out architecture with (sub-)orchestrators and a lot of activities running in parallel is required. Additionally, all these activities have to interact with an Azure blob storage account. When dealing with this high degree of parallelization, I often run into runtime errors like these:

```
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.859Z] 4c6a215f040141aaaa995f9cfbf1a234:10: An error occurred while processing message [TaskScheduled#46]: DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.DurableTaskStorageException: The specified pop receipt did not match the pop receipt for a dequeued message.[2023-02-07T14:11:36.860Z]  ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The specified pop receipt did not match the pop receipt for a dequeued message.
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.861Z]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)[2023-02-07T14:11:36.874Z]    at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.AzureStorageClient.WrapFunctionWithReturnType(Func`3 storageRequest, OperationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Storage/AzureStorageClient.cs:line 156[2023-02-07T14:11:36.875Z]    at DurableTask.AzureStorage.TimeoutHandler.ExecuteWithTimeout[T](String operationName, String account, AzureStorageOrchestrationServiceSettings settings, Func`3 operation, AzureStorageOrchestrationServiceStats stats, String clientRequestId)[2023-02-07T14:11:36.876Z]    at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.AzureStorageClient.MakeStorageRequest[T](Func`3 storageRequest, String accountName, String operationName, String clientRequestId, Boolean force)
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.877Z] Request Information
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.879Z] RequestID:7db00ba3-1e70-42fc-84f5-f6dfb9ec630a
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.880Z] RequestDate:Tue, 07 Feb 2023 15:11:36 GMT
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.896Z] StatusMessage:The specified pop receipt did not match the pop receipt for a dequeued message.
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.897Z] ErrorCode:PopReceiptMismatch
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.898Z] ErrorMessage:The specified pop receipt did not match the pop receipt for a dequeued message.
RequestId:7db00ba3-1e70-42fc-84f5-f6dfb9ec630a
Time:2023-02-07T14:11:36.137Z
[2023-02-07T14:11:36.901Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

These neither trigger try-catch breakpoints nor stop code execution, but are really annoying and cause the orchestrators to restart which leads to data corruption down the road. Is there a proper way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

When function projects get created in Visual Studio, the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value in the `local.settings.json` file is set to `true` by default. Configuring Azure functions to use a real storage account for orchestrators can eliminate concurrency issues and faulty state management. Simply replace the value with the connection string of your own storage:

```
{
  ...
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE]",
    ...
  }
}
```